# Limitation Google maps

Tags: google-maps

I can not build more than 10 route in Google Maps, but I think this restriction is not found in the documentation limit on the number of the route, there is a restriction on the intermediate points (8). Then what could be the problem?

```
function requestDirections(start, end, polylineOpts, ways, image) {

        if (ways.length > 0) {
            var waypts = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < ways.length; i++) {
                waypts.push({
                    location: ways[i][0] + ", " + ways[i][1],
                    stopover: true
                });
            }
            directionsService.route({
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                waypoints: waypts,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function (result) {
                renderDirections(result, polylineOpts, image);
            });
        } else {
            directionsService.route({
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                //waypoints: waypts,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function (result) {
                renderDirections(result, polylineOpts, image);
            });
        }

    }


 function beretCoordinate() {
        var routesId = document.getElementsByName('routesId');
        var k = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < routesId.length; i++) {
            var routesId2 = routesId[i].value.replace('~', '').split(',');
            var startMassiv = 0;
            var index = 0;
            var mapPoints = document.getElementsByName(routesId2[0]);
            var start;
            var end;
            for (var j = 0; j < mapPoints.length; j++) {
                routes[j] = mapPoints[j].value.replace(',', '.').replace(',', '.').replace('+', ',').replace('+', ',').replace('+', ',').split(',');
                if (i >= routesId.length) {
                    pointsMap[k]=[routes[j][0], routes[j][1], routes[j][2]];
                    k++;
                    //marshrutCount++;
                } else {
                    if (startMassiv == 0) {

                        var startRoute = routes[j];
                        end = startRoute[0] + ", " + startRoute[1];
                    } else {

                        if (startMassiv == 9 || startMassiv == mapPoints.length - 1) {

                            var endRoute = routes[j];
                            start = endRoute[0] + ", " + endRoute[1];
                            var icons2 = {
                                link: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                                 // URL
                                 routes[j][2],
                                 // (width,height)
                                 new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
                                 // The origin point (x,y)
                                 new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                                 // The anchor point (x,y)
                                 new google.maps.Point(25, 46)
                                )
                            };
                            //calcRoute(start, end, findRoutes);
                            requestDirections(start, end, { strokeColor: routesId2[1] }, findRoutes, { icon: icons2.link });
                            //DrawRoute(findeRoutes, "red");
                            startMassiv = -1;
                            index = 0;
                            findRoutes = [];
                            //marshrutCount++;
                        } else {

                            findRoutes[index] = routes[j];
                            index++;
                        }
                    }

                    startMassiv++;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `renderDirections` look like?  Are you checking the status of the request?  It is probably OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directions service is subject to a quota and a rate limit as wall.

Check the status returned by the directions request:

```
function requestDirections(start, end, polylineOpts, ways, image) {
    if (ways.length > 0) {
        var waypts = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < ways.length; i++) {
            waypts.push({
                location: ways[i][0] + ", " + ways[i][1],
                stopover: true
            });
        }
        directionsService.route({
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            waypoints: waypts,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function (result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              renderDirections(result, polylineOpts, image);
            } else {
              alert("Directions request failed:"+status);
            }
        });
    } else {
        directionsService.route({
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            //waypoints: waypts,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function (result,status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              renderDirections(result, polylineOpts, image);
            } else {
              alert("Directions request failed:"+status);
            }
        });
    }

}
```